# How to limit the the input values for HTML to just values in a predefined list?

Tags: html

I need to deploy one of ML models as a web application. I am working to use HTML to get the input data and pass it to ML model for a live prediction. One of the inputs for this ML model is a 5 digit code. The code should be one of the predefined codes like one in this list [19827, 87198, 18288, ....], which contains 1000 unique values. The user should enter such a code. I want to tell the user whether the input code is valid or not. I am using the following line:

```
<input type="number" name="code" placeholder="code" min="10000" max="99999" step="1" pattern="\d+"/><br>
```

but this does not limit the input to the above list. For example, if user enter a code like 22222 and if that is not in the list the web app should tell the user that this is not valid. How can I do this one in a very efficient and professional way?

Comment: Do you want to give suggestions while user types? like auto suggestion? in such case please refer [datalist attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: Added javascript to load options.

You can use a datalist to limit what the user inputs, like this:

```
<label>Choose an ML code from this list:
<input list="codes" name="myCode" />
</label>
<datalist id="codes"> 
</datalist>
```

Javascript in the `<head>` portion of the page loads options when the page loads:

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "codes.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;  
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Code");
  var options = "";
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    options += '<option value="' +
    x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    '">';
  }
  document.getElementById("codes").innerHTML = options;
}
document.onload(loadDoc);
</script>
```

In this example, you would have an XML data file in the same folder as the HTML file. Alternately, you could load the codes from a database. Doing so would require some server-side code written in a language such as C#, PHP, Python, etc.

Example codes.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<codes>  
  <code>19827</code>
  <code>87198</code>
  <code>18288</code>
  <code>19555</code>
  <code>21456</code>
  <code>99874</code>
<!-- etc. -->  
</codes>
```

As before, you would also need some additional javascript to validate the input.

Comment: I can use this but I do not want to repeat this line of code 1000 times. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: in such case, you just need to make an ajax call to the backend service which will provide you the list of data and you can fill in this data on the go. You not need to write all data manually.

Comment: Can you please share a helping example for that please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make this with HTML because HTML is a markup language.
You should make this with PHP or python. in the frontend, you should make input static and in the backend, you can make this dynamic.

Code in python :

```
passcodes = ['1234' , '6523' , '8390'] #You can change this.

user_passcode = input("Enter your passcode: ")

if user_passcode in passcodes :
    print("password is true")
else :
    print("password is false")
```

Comment: I did the same with Python. I saw many website that when you are typing the first digit the input comes up and you can select among them or continue typing.